# How to center title of multicolumn only on the multicolumns, not on all columns?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the following example LaTeX table code:

```
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{all clusters} \\
\cline{2-5}
clust. size & no. clust. & (\%) & no. spec. & (\%) \\
\hline
1      & 12403    & 68.9\% & 127834 & 22.7\%  \\
2      & 2343     & 45.5\% & 13434  & 15.6\%  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want 'all clusters' in the center of the columns `no. clust.`, `(\%)`, `no. spec.` and `(\%)`. However, now it also takes `clust. size` in consideration with centering, so the text gets put on top of `no. clust.`, instead of in between `no. clust` and `(\%).

How can I center this column title on only what is in the second multicolumn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you miss `&` in front of `\multicolumn{4}{c}{all clusters}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\hline
&\multicolumn{4}{c}{all clusters} \\
\cline{2-5}
clust. size & no. clust. & (\%) & no. spec. & (\%) \\
\hline
1      & 12403    & 68.9\% & 127834 & 22.7\%  \\
2      & 2343     & 45.5\% & 13434  & 15.6\%  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ops.. @somkiat_t already answered, sorry